# Set a audio bitrate cap in ffmpeg

Tags: command-line, audio, ffmpeg, conversion, mp3

I want to set a maximum audio bitrate in my FFmpeg conversions, but it seems like the only option is to specify a constant one like `-c:a libopus -b:a 128K`

It would allow FFmpeg to only compress audio down to a specified bitrate if the converted file contains an audio with a higher bitrate than the specified value

Is there a workaround for this?

Comment: possibly duplicate of https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43435712/how-to-set-bitrate-limit-in-ffmpeg

Answer (score 0):

**Short Answer**

```
ffmpeg -i input_file.wav -b 128k -minrate 64k -maxrate 192k output_file.mp3
```

**A little longer one:**

Looks like you're thinking of variable bit rate (VBR) in which bitrate changes according to need for maintaining constant quality or an average bitrate.

For that, use `-q` switch

```
ffmpeg -i input_file.wav -q 4 output_file.mp3
```

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Comment: Thanks a lot! And about the other post, I thought it was talking about video bitrates, so I thought my question wasn't a duplicate